# Showing a function is strictly convex when defined as infimum of other strictly convex function

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, convex-analysis

Let $T: X \to Y$ be continuous and linear. I need to show that $g:Y \to [0,\infty]$ defined as:
$$
g(y) = \inf_{x: T(x) = y} \{f(x)\}, \quad y \in Y
$$
is strictly convex if the function $f:X \to [0, \infty]$ is strictly convex on its domain.
So we choose some $y_1, y_2 \in Y$ and $\lambda \in [0,1]$, but how do we get past:
$$
g(\lambda y_1 + (1-\lambda)y_2) = \inf_{x:T(x) = \lambda y_1 + (1-\lambda)y_2} \{f(x)\}
$$
I think I need to use the linearity of $T$ somehow but I am unsure as to how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $x_1$ and $x_2$ such that $Tx_1=y_1$ and $Tx_2=y_2$. Then
$$
g(\lambda y_1 + (1-\lambda) y_2) \le f(\lambda x_1 + (1-\lambda) x_2)
$$
by definition of $g$ and $T(\lambda x_1 + (1-\lambda) x_2)=\lambda y_1 + (1-\lambda) y_2$.
By convexity
$$
f(\lambda x_1 + (1-\lambda) x_2) \le \lambda f(x_1) + (1-\lambda) f(x_2),
$$
so that
$$
g(\lambda y_1 + (1-\lambda) y_2) \le\lambda f(x_1) + (1-\lambda) f(x_2).
$$
Now we can take the infimum over $x_1$ and $x_2$ on the right-hand side, which proves
$$
g(\lambda y_1 + (1-\lambda) y_2) \le\lambda g(y_1) + (1-\lambda) g(y_2),
$$
and $g$ is convex.

---

$g$ needs not to be strictly convex if $f$ is strictly convex.
Take $f:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ defined by
$$
f(x) = \exp(x_1) + \exp(x_2),
$$
and $T:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ defined by
$$
T(x) = x_1 - x_2.
$$
Then
$$
\inf_{x_1 - x_2 = y} (\exp(x_1) + \exp(x_2))
\le \inf_{x_1} (\exp(x_1) + \exp(x_1 -y)) = 0,
$$
so that $g(y) \equiv 0$.